# How to get a different number by repeating an id by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

Each id in a page repeats 2 times (if it was once, it's still good)

I want a code script for these

```
<button onclick="myFunction('<div id="my-id">')">Button</button>
<div id="<div id="my-id">"></div>

<button onclick="myFunction('<div id="my-id">')">Button</button>
<div id="<div id="my-id">"></div>

<button onclick="myFunction('<div id="my-id">')">Button</button>
<div id="<div id="my-id">"></div>

                           ?work?

<button onclick="myFunction('1')">Button</button>
<div id="1"></div>

<button onclick="myFunction('2')">Button</button>
<div id="2"></div>

<button onclick="myFunction('3')">Button</button>
<div id="3"></div>
                                      ...
```

Comment: id must be unique. use class

Comment: ids must be unique. The second one is never found.

Comment: also, are you sure you need html in your ids?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking for. If you're just talking about generating that HTML, start off with a loop `for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {}`, inside that, concatenate the string containing your HTML...

Answer (score 0):

Id needs to be unique. Use class to mark butto0ns where you will generate id on next siblings and add event listener:

To generate sibling div with unique id on click:

```
let i = 0;


[...document.querySelectorAll('.click')].forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    let div = document.createElement("div")
    div.id = ++i;
    //generate unique id: ++i
    div.innerHTML = i;
    // to use it after generate use just i
    event.target.parentNode.insertBefore(div,event.target.nextSibling);
    //add sibiling after button click
  })
})
```

**EXAMPLE**

```js
let i = 0;


[...document.querySelectorAll('.click')].forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    let div = document.createElement("div")
    div.id = ++i;
    //generate unique id: ++i
    div.innerHTML = i;
    // to use it after generate use just i
    event.target.parentNode.insertBefore(div,event.target.nextSibling);
    //add sibiling after button click
  })
})
```

```html
<button class="click">Button</button>


<button class="click">Button</button>


<button class="click">Button</button>
```

Generate id and add it to next sibling div:**

```
let i = 0;


[...document.querySelectorAll('.click')].forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.target.nextElementSibling.id = ++i;
    //generate unique id: ++i

    event.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = event.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML + " id:" + i;
    // add it innerhtml just to show

    console.clear();
    console.log(event.target.nextElementSibling.id);
    //show new id of element
  })
})
```

**EXAMPLE**

```js
let i = 0;

[...document.querySelectorAll('.click')].forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.target.nextElementSibling.id = ++i;
    //generate unique id: ++i

    event.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = event.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML + " id:" + i;
    // add it innerhtml just to show

    console.clear();
    console.log(event.target.nextElementSibling.id);
    //show new id of element
  })
})
```

```html
<button class="click">Button</button>
<div>test div</div>

<button class="click">Button</button>
<div>test div</div>

<button class="click">Button</button>
<div>test div</div>
```

If you need to use something unique on click on multiple elements generate unique CSS class and apply on those elements:

```
let i = 0;

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', event => {
  let clickClass = "clickClass" + (++i);
  //generate unique class: clickClass++i
  [...document.querySelectorAll('div')].forEach(div => {
    div.classList.add(clickClass);
    //add class to each div

    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + " " + clickClass;
    // add it innerhtml just to show
  })
})
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
let i = 0;

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', event => {
  let clickClass = "clickClass" + (++i);
  //generate unique class: clickClass++i
  [...document.querySelectorAll('div')].forEach(div => {
    div.classList.add(clickClass);
    //add class to each div

    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + " " + clickClass;
    // add it innerhtml just to show
  })
})
```

```html
<button class="click">Button</button>
<div>test div</div>
<div>test div</div>
<div>test div</div>
```